# c# 9.0 covariant return types and interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, covariance, c#-9.0

I have two code examples:

One compiles

```
    class C {
        public virtual object Method2() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    class D : C {
        public override string Method2() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Another one does not

```
    interface A {
        object Method1();
    }

    class B : A {
        public string Method1() => throw new NotImplementedException();
        // Error    CS0738  'B' does not implement interface member 'A.Method1()'. 'B.Method1()' cannot implement 'A.Method1()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'object'.  ConsoleApp2 C:\Projects\Experiments\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs  14  Active

    }
```

How covariant return types work in C# 9.0 and why it does not work with interfaces?

Comment: [Covariant returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns): "The remainder of the draft specification below proposes a further extension to covariant returns of interface methods **to be considered later.**"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Did not spot this remark there. Thanks!

Comment: One approach would be to change A to an abstract class.  Yet another approach would be to add an abstract class which derives from A which has a virtual Method1 and then derive B from that abstract class.  Both options are ugly.  It may be better to wait for C# to support interface methods as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whilst covariant return types in interfaces are not supported as of C# 9, there is a simple workaround:

```cs
    interface A {
        object Method1();
    }

    class B : A {
        public string Method1() => throw new NotImplementedException();
        object A.Method1() => Method1();
    }
```

Comment: I can't seem to apply this solution to any sort of collection property in the interface when there's a generic involved. Can you show what to do when object is a IList<Foo>?

Comment: @NWoodsman it should be exactly the same. Can you show what code isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, I was inadvertently trying to get generic covariance with an `IList<IFoo>`.

Comment: this seems to work, however I wonder what would be the case when `public string Method1() => throw new NotImplementedException();` is called? I would like to understand it better and avoid mistakes.

Comment: While this perfectly answers how to overcome the issue, it does not answer the question per se.

Comment: Is this still not possible in 2023 ?