# C# interface method with generic return type of implements interface (Bounds)

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a `DeepCopyable` interface that looks like this:

```
public interface DeepCopyable
{
    public T DeepCopy<T>() /* where T : DeepCopyable */; // i know this doesn't work
}
```

I want to make sure that the implementing classes implement like this:
I don't know how to archive this with an interface, how do I specify the return type correctly to be of type of the implementing class?

```
public class A : DeepCopyable
{
    public int a { get; set; } = 0;
    public B b { get; set; } = new B();

    public A DeepCopy() 
    {
        return new A()
        {
            a = a,
            b = b.DeepCopy()
        };
    }
}

public class B : DeepCopyable
{
    public int a { get; set; } = 0;

    public B DeepCopy()
    {
        return new B()
        {
            a = a
        };
    }
}
public class C : DeepCopyable
{
    public int a { get; set; } = 0;

    public B DeepCopy() //This Should be not allowed
    {
        return new B()
        {
            a = a
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Naming convention zero points. Could you maybe provide more details or a better explanation? Any class that inherits an interface has to implements all its methods, Which you have done with class A and class B. What is the error code if there is one?

Comment: You're going to need a `DeepCopyable<T>` interface, preferably called `IDeepCopyable<T>` to comply with the convention.

Comment: @JosipJuros i have added class C in my example to illustrate what should be not allowed
@ JohnathanBarclay would you be able to provide a code example? I think I am a little confused with this issue

Comment: There's also nothing in your code to suggest that an interface is needed at all, considering you only call `DeepCopy()` on the specific types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is like this:

```cs
public interface IDeepCopyable<T>
    where T : IDeepCopyable<T>
{
    T DeepCopy();
}

public class A : IDeepCopyable<A>
{
    public int a { get; set; } = 0;
    public B b { get; set; } = new B();

    public A DeepCopy() 
    {
        return new A()
        {
            a = a,
            b = b.DeepCopy()
        };
    }
}

public class B : IDeepCopyable<B>
{
    public int a { get; set; } = 0;

    public B DeepCopy()
    {
        return new B()
        {
            a = a
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Why constrain `T` to be an `IDeepCopyable<T>`?

Comment: Too bad there isn't a way to "just tell" the implementing class to return of type itself.

Comment: That wouldn't make sense in the non-generic approach, considering all implementing classes must declare the exact same signature. With the generic version you _are_ telling the class to return itself, by passing itself as the generic type. How else could the syntax look?

Comment: It's a shame C# doesn't support return type covariance for interface implementations yet.  (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230700/c-sharp-9-0-covariant-return-types-and-interfaces)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can make the classes that inherit from the interface and implement the method with a specified return type of type of the derived class

```
  interface IDeepCopy<T>
    {
        T testMethod();

    }
    class Test1 : IDeepCopy<Test1>
    {
        public Test1 testMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```