# What are possible difficulties in implementing return type covariance for interfaces?

Tags: c#, overriding, covariance

The question is highly related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230700/c-sharp-9-0-covariant-return-types-and-interfaces) one. The support of return types covariance for overriden methods was added to C# only in version 9, and still interfaces are not supported. I'm not interested in how to overcome this (the linked question has a valid answer already), but I wonder what are possible underlying problems with covariance return types support in C#.

I mean, C++ had covariance return type support for a very long time since C++98. What is different in C#, which makes the support of return type covariance an issue? What are the possible difficulties in the implementation? From my naive point of view, it's just the matter of extending a compilation check: instead of requiring an exact return type match, you allow inheritance. And this is already done for classes. What am I missing here?

The purpose of the question is not to compare which language is better, but to understand the rationale behind the issue, which will in turn help to understand the language better, which in turn will help to use the language better.

Comment: Why? Well you need to ask the language developers, we can't answer that question here.

Comment: @DavidG isn't there any chance that some of C# language developers are here on SO, or that there is someone in SO clever enough to answer the question, while not being C# language developer?

Comment: @AlexChe I used to work on Visual Studio at Microsoft and I have no idea either :)

Comment: [Recommended reading.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585)

Comment: I'm uncertain that you're using the word "covariance" correctly here because generic `interface` types with `class` constraints with variance modifiers _do_ have support for return-type covariance (with exceptions, like `Task<T>`). Can you edit your question-post to demonstrate which _specific_ limitation of C# (of which there are many...) you're referring to?

Comment: When the workaround is as trivial as this, you gotta have a very good justification why development effort should be spent on this first, as opposed to some other more important features, that doesn't have such a trivial workaround. Just my two cents.

Comment: _"I mean, C++ had covariance return type support for a very long time since C++98"_ - C++'s templates are not generics: template-instantiation is much closer to C-style macros than C#'s _reified generics_, - I wouldn't say that C++ was specifically designed to support it, but that it just-works as a side-effect of how C++ is compiled.

Comment: @Dai the linked question has an example of code. Do you want me to copy-paste it here? Also generics and templates are not related to this question at all. Please read [covariant return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type)

Comment: @Sweeper totally agree. My question is why covariance return type support did even required any additional work.

Comment: @AlexChe My mistake - I assumed you were referring to variant generic interfaces because that's chiefly what people used-to refer to when mentioning covariance/contravariance w.r.t. C#/.NET (...or array-types).

Comment: And no, this question is not opinion-based. There are objective reasons for why this feature is not present in C#. I agree that questions like this one are often hard to answer, but (a) much of the C# design process happens transparently on github, which makes such questions much more answerable than they have been a decade ago and (b) those question are much more interesting than the 2000-th iteration of *"why does this code that I copied-and-pasted together without understanding it not do what I want it to do"*.

Comment: @Heinzi More relevant dupe [Does C# support return type covariance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709034/does-c-sharp-support-return-type-covariance)

Comment: @Charlieface: I don't see how this proposed dupe answers the question about *why* this is not supported in interfaces.

Comment: It already exists, look at your generic enumerators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more complicated than it sounds, since it would lead to breaking changes.

The [specification for Covariant Return Types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns.md) also contains a draft for supporting covariance in interfaces. It includes the following section, which I will quote verbatim (emphasis mine):

> [The proposed specification for interface covariance] is technically a breaking change, as the program below prints "C1.M" today, but would print "C2.M" under the proposed revision.
>
> ```
> using System;
>
> interface I1 { object M(); }
> class C1 : I1 { public object M() { return "C1.M"; } }
> class C2 : C1, I1 { public new string M() { return "C2.M"; } }
> class Program
> {
>     static void Main()
>     {
>         I1 i = new C2();
>         Console.WriteLine(i.M());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **Due to this breaking change, we might consider not supporting covariant return types on implicit implementations.**

The on-going discussion about this feature can be found here:

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/49

Not much has happened in the last years, so I guess this is currently not considered to be a high-priority extension by the community.

Comment: But the `new` modifier means the `C2.M` method makes a new slot that shadows, rather than overrides, the interfaces's virtual-call - presumably return-type covariance could be handled by using a different keyword modifier?

Comment: I totally forgot about the obvious possibility of breaking existing code. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Dai: It shadows C1's implementation of `M`, it does not shadow the interface. Consider the case where C1 does not implement I1: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n8HdOc

Comment: @Dai: Here's a more complete example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNLALp