# Abstract property that can accept a derived type in the overridden property

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, abstract-class

Let's say I have an abstract class called `StuffBase` with an abstract property of type `IEnumerable`:

```
abstract class StuffBase
{
    public abstract IEnumerable SomeStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Now, is it possible to define a derived class that overrides the `SomeStuff` property with a *derived* type, like, for instance:

```
class StuffDerived : StuffBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<int> SomeStuff { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that `IEnumerable<int>` is derived from `IEnumerable`. Is there any way to achieve something like this? When I currently try this, it gives me the error **"StuffDerived does not implement abstract member StuffBase.SomeStuff.Set"**.

**But here's what I don't quite get:** If the abstract class only defines a **getter**, but *not* a **setter**, then *it works*. For instance, if `SomeStuff` is defined as

```
public abstract IEnumerable SomeStuff { get; }
```

and

```
public override IEnumerable<int> SomeStuff { get; }
```

it works perfectly fine. An explanation for this would also be nice.

Comment: `public abstract IEnumerable SomeStuff { get; }` defines a **new** "slot" for a new property which is a distinct property entirely separate from `public override IEnumerable<int> SomeStuff { get; }` - you'll get a compiler warning about missing the `new` modifier for explicit shadowing.

Comment: @Dai If the abstract and overriden properties only have getters but **not** setters, then it compiles with no issues. It's only a problem when I add the setters, which is what I don't understand.

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230700/c-sharp-9-0-covariant-return-types-and-interfaces - C# 9.0 introduced return-type variance for virtual methods and properties in `class` types - but not `interface` types.

Comment: Remember, if it worked the way you wanted, with that setter on the base class, `StuffBase b = new StuffDerived(); b.SomeStuff = new AnythingThatImplementsIEnumerable();` would compile but that derived class isn't anticipating anything other that `IEnumerable<int>` derived classes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah, that actually makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is called [covariant return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns) and was introduced in C# 9:

> Support covariant return types. Specifically, permit the override of a method to declare a more derived return type than the method it overrides, and similarly to permit the override of a read-only property to declare a more derived type. Override declarations appearing in more derived types would be required to provide a return type at least as specific as that appearing in overrides in its base types. Callers of the method or property would statically receive the more refined return type from an invocation.

Note that if the setter would work like you have desired it would break the class contract. I.e. consider the following:

```
var foo =  new StuffDerived()
StuffBase bar = foo;
bar.SomeStuff = new List<object> {"hahah"};
int i = foo.First(); // boom
```

You can use generics to "workaround" to some extent the setter problem:

```cs
abstract class StuffBase<T>
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> SomeStuff { get; set; }
}

class StuffDerived : StuffBase<int>
{
    public override IEnumerable<int> SomeStuff { get; set; }
}
```

But it has some limitations like `StuffDerived` is not `StuffBased<object>` (i.e. `StuffBase<object> foo = new StuffDerived();` will not compile). You can workaround a bit more with some base interface and explicit interface implementation, but again with no setter:

```
interface IStuff
{
    IEnumerable SomeStuff { get; }
}
abstract class StuffBase<T> : IStuff
{
    IEnumerable IStuff.SomeStuff => SomeStuff;
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> SomeStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Actually some similar "problems" a relevant to "ordinary" variance in C# so you can read also:

- [Covariance and Contravariance (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)
- [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2033912/2501279)